# Buying / Selling tokens through the JSON RPC API

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, rpc

Just started developing in Solana and have been playing around with the solana/web3.js package. My current goal is to buy / sell live tokens. Does anyone know if this is possible to do through the JSON RPC or would it have to be done with a smart contract? (I've had a look at the JSON RPC docs and it doesn't look like there is a buy / sell method, is anybody able to confirm?)

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Solana/web3.js only allows transfer's for SOL if you want to do transfer for SPL Tokens than you have to use the solana/spl-token library

Answer (score 1):

RPC nodes do not make markets, so there is no JSON RPC API to match buyers and sellers of assets.